# Can plant roots absorb dissolved oxygen from water, or do they require actual bubbles in the water?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

Plant roots generally require some exposure to air.  [Deep water culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_water_culture) is a form of hydroponics where plants' roots are left to soak in water.  To keep the roots from "suffocating", most [online sources](http://www.homehydrosystems.com/hydroponic-systems/water-culture_systems.html) recommend some kind of aeration mechanism, such as an [air stone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0081VQZS6).

These systems normally wind up filling the water with bubbles, right under the plants.  So my question is: are the bubbles responsible for keeping the plants alive, or is the dissolved oxygen keeping the plants alive?  So for example, could plants live immediately downstream of a waterfall (a natural aerator), even out of range of its bubbles?